# Error on MonoGame Content Pipeline: Texture Importer Error

Tags: xna, monogame, xna-content-pipeline, pipeline, png

I just encountered this kind of error when using the MonoGame Content Pipeline and it's my first time to use it to convert png to xnb files (I use a stand alone app for converting files to xnb in the past). I've done building spritefonts to xnb files and stuff like that in my previous MonoGame projects and I thought it would be similar but it turned out to be not the case.

So this is the error I have:

```
error: Importer 'TextureImporter' had unexpected failure!
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter.Import (System.String filename, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporterContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporter`1[Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics.TextureContent].Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentImporter.Import (System.String filename, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporterContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent (MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineBuildEvent pipelineEvent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is there a way to resolve this? Is there a tutorial of some kind I can follow to use the TextureImporter and the things I haven't yet understood on MonoGame's Content Pipeline with in-depth explanation about it?

Comment: Show us the relevant code that causes the error

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the monogame content tool? I believe there was a bug related to this. (See https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/4000 )

Comment: @Shiro There is no code involved as I am just trying to convert png files to xnb files using the MGCB.

Comment: @Felsir I think I have similar MGCB version which is 3.5.0.344 that fails. I see... I'll look into this. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013.

---

These two posts on https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/3556 worked for me:

**tomspilman**:

> Hum... the redist we need vcredist_x64.exe is only 7MB. If you download and run it from the command line:
>
> vcredist_x64.exe -?
>
> It tells you that it has /quiet and /norestart mode:
>
> We should be able to embed this into the Windows installer fairly easily if we want.
>
> Either that or we just add a note about it on the download site.

**gms9rc**:

> Problem solved. Despite the fact that I am using VS2012 I needed to install the 2013 redistributable. Right here for anyone who comes across this problem https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784